# Searching a different dictionary depending on what Radio Button is selected

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have a program that uses libraries to retrieve notes on a keyword.
Currently it works great however I wanted to add in a feature that would allow me to select different dictionaries to pull a different set of notes using radio buttons to change what dictionary I am currently searching in.

Dictionaries being called:

```
rms_notes = { "SomeKey" : "Some random notes" }
vzt_notes = { "SomeKey" : "Some random notes" }
nsr_notes = { "SomeKey" : "Some random notes" }
```

So my RadioButtons are as follows.

```
RaBu1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,text="Lib1",variable = vl, value = 1)
RaBu2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,text="Lib2",variable = vl, value = 2)
RaBu3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,text="Lib3",variable = vl, value = 3)
RaBu1.place(#all the formatting here)
RaBu2.place(#all the formatting here)
RaBu3.place(#all the formatting here)
```

for now my libraries are called using:

```
keywordEntry = Entry(root)
keywordEntry.bind('<Return>', kw_entry)
KeywordEntry.place(#all the formatting here)
```

And the function I use to access each different dictionary while a radio button is selected is as follows:

```
v1 = IntVar()
def kw_entry(event=None):
    libvar = v1.get()
    e1Current = keywordEntry.get().lower()
    if libvar == 1:
        if e1Current in rms_notes:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, rms_notes[e1Current])
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
        else:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "Not a Keyword")
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
    elif libvar == 2:
        if e1Current in vzt_notes:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, vzt_notes[e1Current])
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
        else:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "Not a Keyword")
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
    elif libvar == 3:
        if e1Current in nsr_notes:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, nsr_notes[e1Current])
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
        else:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "Not a Keyword")
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
    else:
        root.text.delete(1.0, END)
        root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "No Library select")
        root.text.see(tkinter.END)
```

This works how I expected but I am wondering is there a better way to call each dictionary into this function? It just feels like there should be a cleaner way to perform this task with a shorter code.

I could be wrong but if anyone has some ideas or input on the matter I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging and taking what `Daniel.VanWagnen` wrote as a starting point I figured out how to condense my if statement down.

I had to create a dictionary that contained the names of the different dictionaries I had made to store my notes in. I made sure to create the keys to match the values from the radioButtons variables. This allowed me to use the current variable to call the stored dictionary name and use it in the rest of the `if` statement.

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this however I have managed to condense the code down to a smarter if statement than what I had before.

Now all I have to do in order to update this in the future if I were to add more note sections is to add a new radioButton and take the next available value (in this case `4`) and add the new `value:dict_name` to my vrange dictionary.

I am sure I can stream line this as well and I will be working on that also but for now this is the answer to my original question if anyone is interested.

```
v1 = IntVar()


def update_var(event=None):
    current_var = v1.get()
    e1Current = keywordEntry.get().lower()
    vrange= {1: vzt_notes,2:rms_notes,3:nsr_notes}
    if current_var in vrange:
        note_var = vrange[current_var]
        if e1Current in note_var:
            note_var = vrange[current_var]
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, note_var[e1Current])
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
        else:
            root.text.delete(1.0, END)
            root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "Not a Keyword")
            root.text.see(tkinter.END)
    else:
        root.text.delete(1.0, END)
        root.text.insert(tkinter.END, "No Library Selected")
        root.text.see(tkinter.END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hold them in an array of dicts, using the index of the array, and the radio button variable value to access the dict in question. Once your dicts are declared, something like:

```
dict_Container = [rms_notes, vzt_notes, nsr_notes]
```

Then:

```
if e1Current in dictContainer[libvar]:
```